# Call to undefined function setUseContainer()

Tags: magento-1.9, error, forms, adminform

I keep getting this error when I view my form in Magento admin:

> Call to undefined function setUseContainer() in app\code\local\MasteringMagento\Example\Block\Adminhtml\Event\Edit\Form.php

Please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

```
class MasteringMagento_Example_Block_Adminhtml_Event_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
        array('id' => 'edit_form',
              'action' => $this->getData('action'),
              'method' => 'post'
        )
    );

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',array('legend'=> Mage::helper('example')->__('General Information'),'class'=> 'fieldset-wide'));

    $fieldset->addField('name','text',array(
        'name'    => 'name',
        'label'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Event Name'),
        'title'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Event Name'),
        'required' => true
    ));

    $dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

    $fieldset->addField('start','date',array(
        'name'     => 'start',
        'format'   => $dateFormatIso,
        'image'    => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'label'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Start Date'),
        'title'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Start Date'),
        'required' => true
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('end','date',array(
        'name'     => 'end',
        'format'   => $dateFormatIso,
        'image'    => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'label'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Start Date'),
        'title'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Start Date'),
        'required' => true
    ));

    $form = setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);


    return parent::_prepareForm();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
$form = setUseContainer(true);
```

to the:

```
$form->setUseContainer(true);
```

because the `setUseContainer` is not a function, it is a magic method of the `Varien_Data_Form`

Comment: @user2531490 I'm glad to help you